# Mounting an extra partition as a fake external SD card

Tags: external-sd, partitions, magisk

Nowadays phones don't have SD cards anymore, but some have a ton of storage. So, I was thinking of creating a fake external SD card using an extra partition to be able to store all of your zip flashable files, pictures, and music and have it stay when you inevitably format user data when flashing a ROM or whatever.

My question is: **How to properly mount a partition as an SD card so that Android thinks you have an external SD?** (you see it in a file manager, can store pictures on it directly, etc.)

What I've done already :

- I have created an extra partition on my OnePlus 6 with `parted`, it's `sda17`
- I have successfully mounted this partition to be able to use it normally
  (`mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/block/sda17 /external_sd`)
  This command allows you to navigate to `/external_sd` and see your files, but Android doesn't think that you have an external SD card.

I'm thinking of using a Magisk module to mount everything properly at every boot (if this is even possible)

Comment: Its not true that phones dont have sdcards anymore.  I still have them in the latest Samsung phones.  Whats the purpose in making internal storage into sdcard ?  It makes no sense to me.  For me, the main advantage of an sdcard is that you can just transfer it to your new phone. How will this help ?

Comment: Every time you flash a custom rom the entire userdata partition is formatted (for a clean flash). If i were to buy a Redmi note 12 turbo with 1TB of storage, I'd like to allocate some of that space to have some form of permanent storage for photos, music, etc... Having it be a fake sd card would just allow apps to recognise it (if it's a directory in the root of the filesystem you can only access it with a rooted explorer, or termux).
Also you are right, there are new samsung phones with sd cards, but none are good. They are less powerful that my 150€ Poco X3 Pro with less features.

Answer (score 1):

Its just not possible and even if it was you would need root, jbrim**** is right also, every time you factory reset it'll wipe ALL user data including newly created partions....

Comment: Of course you need root to do that kind of black magic ;) ! Keep in mind I've already gotten an extra partition mounted and I have file on it on my test phone. It's already useful to store my app bakcups and zips for TWRP and Magisk as a permanent storage, so that part is confirmed. Really what I don't know is if "fooling android into displaying that partition as if it were an sdcard" is possible.